# VSTO Outlook: Outlook.MailItem.Copy() Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT))

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am getting Operation aborted error when trying to create a new instance of an Outlook.MailItem.

```
Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)this.MyMailItem?.Copy();
```

MyMailItem is not null and Count=1 but I am not able to perform that copy. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where does `MyMailItem` come from? Is it saved?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko it comes from a compose window, I mean, I open a compose window in order to write an email, then I start typing in email addresses in the "To" field, and after each email address is entered I handle the event in MailItem_PropertyChanged and I am trying to create another instance of it.

Comment: Does it work if you (as a test) call `MyMailItem.Save`? Why would you want to create a copy of the message every time something changes? Even if it works, you'd have exactly same message. How would that help you?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Because when some conditions are satisfied for email address just entered in the "To" field, I need to modify that email address and add a symbol at the beginning. For example change from the one entered "test@foo.com" to "*test@foo.com". All properties are read-only and in case of recipients object i cannot do recipients[pos]=newRecipient (recipients is read-only). I can do recipients.Add(), but I cannot add it in the same index within recipients. I need to maintain the order of email addresses. So I create a new instance of mailitem with recipients recreated.

Comment: Recipient properties can be modified in Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) or Redemption (any language, I am its author), but Outlook won't see the changes until the message is reopened. Is modifying recipients just before the message is sent an option?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko And is it possible to copy this Outlook.Mailitem in another new variable and modify this new variable, for example the "To"  field without the original getting affected by this change?

Comment: Sure, MailItem.Copy should work, but you probably woudl need to save it first (MailItem.Save).

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear where the `MyMailItem` comes from. If it is a new mail item instance you need to call the `Save` method before doing any operations against it.